# I suspect that chrome is sending a request before the user submits it. Is this even possible?

Tags: google-chrome

I've been developing this website and I noticed a strange behavior on chrome. 
When I restart tomcat, it recreates the database (for testing porpuses), and due to this, I've created an URL that populates the database.

The thing is that sometimes when I'm still typing this URL, I check Tomcats access log, and there it is, the request that I hadn't submit got automatically, somehow, submitted.
The server output logs confirm that the this "Ghost request" was sent.

If I do submit the URL that I was typing it repeats the request and then I get an error page because the database has some constraints an the values are repeated.

Is this behavior somehow expected or documented anywhere (if it is, why is it inconsistent?)? has someone experienced something similar to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if chrome makes requests early, but it could and that shouldn't be a problem.

HTTP GET request are considered to be [idempotent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077412/what-is-an-idempotent-operation), which basically means making the request several times shouldn't be any different than making the request only once.  As such if chrome (or any other browser) wanted to make the GET request early to try and pre-load the page so it appears to load faster once the user actually presses enter, there shouldn't be any negative effect of doing so.

Your script to populate the database should not be doing anything to the database when it's made with a GET request and instead wait for a POST request.  For a GET request just have it output a form with a submit button that you can click which will make the POST request to populate your database.

Comment: That explains a lot to me. I'm still learning the basics of HTTP. Could you suggest any article that I can refer to?